# How to exclude delete url from spring security authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, delete-operator, http-status-code-401

I want to exclude the 401 error when trying to access the url, I used the following for the delete function but I still get the error. I know that the problem is with the way I am displaying the delete url with the id, what is the right way?

```
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        // Allow Login API to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login","/addUser","/findAllUsers","/delete/{id}").antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**"); // Request type options should be allowed.
    }
```

Comment: To start with, your API will be easier to work with if you use HTTP verbs correctly: `POST /users` (`/addUser`), `GET /users` (`/findAllUsers`), `DELETE /users/{id}`.

Comment: Try this way: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/addUser","/findAllUsers","/delete/*").permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll;`